# Building and handling multiple param queries with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm a bit lost on how to handle multiple param inputs in a URL to build filters in Rails 3.2

Basically, I would like to take http://example.com/products/?category=24 and http://example.com/products/?category=24&country=24 to work together.

I have the following models `Product`, `Country`, `Category`, `Categorization`

I can build a simple condition in my `ProductController`

```
def index
  @products = product.all

  if params[:country]
    @products = Country.find(params[:country]).products
  end

  if params[:category]
    @products = Category.find(params[:category]).products
  end

end
```

I wanted to know the best way to tackle this since my `Category` and `Product` models through the `Categorization` model through with a has_many association.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :categorization
  belongs_to :country

end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorization
  has_many :products, through: :categorization

  attr_accessible :name

end

class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :product

  attr_accessible :category, :product
end
```

My view layouts template is a simple list of category and country links. So if somebody clicks a category called "Toys" and the clicks on the country "England" it should build a link like so: http://www.example.com/products/category=12&country_id=1

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="products">
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar>
   <h2>Categories</h2>
   <ul>
     <% @categories.each do |category| %>
       <li><%= link_to category.name, params.merge(category: category.id) %></li>
     <% end %>
   </ul>
    <h2>Countries</h2>
   <ul>
     <% @countries.each do |country| %>
       <li><%= link_to country.name, params.merge(country: country.id) %></li>
     <% end %>
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Updated**

I've gone with the suggestion of creating a filter on the model class and the below code works but it seems quite messy and not DRY.. can someone assist on another approach.

```
# Product Model

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base 

  # Search filter
  def self.filter_by_params(params)
    if params.has_key?(:category) && params.has_key?(:country_id)
      scoped.joins(:categorization).where("category_id = ? AND country_id = ?", params[:category], params[:country_id])
    elsif params.has_key?(:category)
      scoped.joins(:categorization).where("category_id = ?", params[:category])
    elsif params.has_key?(:country_id)
      scoped.where(country_id: params[:country_id])
    else
      scoped
    end
  end

end

# Product Controller

def index
  @product = Product.filter_by_params(params)
end
```

Many thanks for any advice.

WD

Comment: I also figured I can keep building conditions but that's probably not a very good way of handling the logic. eg. if params[:category] && params[:country_id].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would change your `ProductsController` as follows:

```
def index
  @products = Product.filter_by_params(params)
end
```

Then in your `Product` model:

```
def self.filter_by_params(params)
  scoped = self.scoped
  scoped = scoped.where(:country_id => params[:country_id]) if params[:country_id]          
  scoped = scoped.where(:category_id => params[:category_id]) if params[:category_id]
  scoped
end
```

You'll need to change your view to pass category_id and country_id.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I'll give this a go and let you know. I didn't know I could retrieve the params hash from the model without assigning it a variable in the Controller.

Comment: You can't, you're passing the params hash into a model method.

Comment: Thanks again Jason. I seem to be having problems when assigning the scoped variable and calling scoped at the end. Giving an error: undefined method `where' for nil:NilClass.

Comment: I updated the answer. The scoped method is a class method on `Product`, so you can do `self.scoped` or `Product.scoped`.

Comment: Thank you so much Jason. I do have an question regarding your suggestion. the second scoped variable (not calling self) if params[:category_id] gives me an error undefined method `where' for nil:NilClass or in my case undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass but calling self on the 2nd scope eg. scoped = self.joins() works. I guess my question is.. do I have to build scopes based on conditions eg. scoped = scoped.where(...)if params[:category] && params[:country_id] && params[:size]. Again, thank you so much or baring with me and helping me out.

Comment: I would separate them. Make the first line of filter_by_parmas be scoped = self.scoped. Then you'll have a local variable you can build on based on the params values.

Comment: Jason, you are a true gentleman. Is there any documentation or site I should read about how this implementation works? Thank you for taking the time, your patience and joy.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#working-with-scopes  Reading through that whole guide would help you a lot on figuring out the best way to query ActiveRecord.